# Apache shiro implied permissions

Tags: java, annotations, shiro

If a user has a permissions `user:edit:1` and I'm using the annotation driven `@RequiresPermissions("user:edit")` why is shiro throwing an exception?  Shouldn't that permission be implied by the fact that they have `user:edit:1`?  If I put `@RequriesPermissions("user:edit:1")` then it works fine but during the context of operation I won't know what 1 is yet so that will be checked later in the method, but I'd like to avoid going into the method at all if they don't have the `user:edit` permission at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"user:edit"` implies `"user:edit:1"` but not the other way around. 
You can keep using `@RequiresPermissions("user:edit")` and then check for the **"1"** in your method. You can also use a wildcard `@RequiresPermissions("user:edit:*")`, which is the exactly the same but I think it's clearer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think, ascandrolis answer is correct, since Shiro documentation states:

> The following however is much less ideal for a runtime check:
>
> `if (SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted("printer:print")) {`
>         `//print the document`
>     `}`
>
> Why? Because the second example says "You must be able to print to any printer for the following code block to execute". But remember that "printer:print" is equivalent to "printer:print:*"!

([Shiro Documentation](http://shiro.apache.org/permissions.html#Permissions-CheckingPermissions))

So `@RequiresPermissions("user:edit:*")` means the same as `@RequiresPermissions("user:edit")`, i.e. that the principal needs to be able to edit any user.

Comment: please, read again the question, the answer and the documentation, read it carefully and pay attention to the wording: What the user "has", what's "required" and what information does the developer know  beforehand.

Comment: sorry if my answer wasn't as clear as I meant it to be. what I was wanting to say is that the two permissions "user:edit" and "user:edit:*" are 100% equivalent, and therefore your suggestion to use the latter simply doesn't solve the op's problem of receiving security exceptions. just try it out for yourself (as I did).

Comment: an alternative might be something like [this](http://blog.42.nl/articles/spring-security-accessing-spring-beans-from-your-security-annotations): doing the shiro-check in a custom bean and call it via annotation, or maybe even better: by using a custom [WebSecurityExpressionRoot](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/expression/WebSecurityExpressionRoot.html), you can get access to the http-request and therefore the id supplied by the client.

Comment: I think ascandroli answer says just that - "user:edit" implies "user:edit:1" but not the other way around, and that "user:edit:*" is the exactly the same as "user:edit"