# Shiro 'Any' Permission Instance

Tags: java, apache, security, shiro

I'm confused about Shiro Permission Format. I have a permission called:

```
'messages:publish:anyThing'
```

A person has the permission:

```
'messages:publish:1(Category ID)'
```

I'm trying to give a permission to any people that have any instance of this permission:

```
'messages:publish'
```

I tried the follow line:

```
if (SecurityUtils.getPrincipal().isPermitted("messages:publish:?"))
```

but without success.

I know that all is * , and how is 'Any'?

Comment: did you resolve this yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5281900/1279987

So you can try this instead:

`if (SecurityUtils.getPrincipal().isPermitted("messages:publish:*"))`